# Visual FoxPro query add total

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have the follwoing simple query which just SUMS the total of 1 or more rows. Based on a unique reference.

What I want to do is add a total column to the results of the jobcharge.nAccrInv grouped by JobRef

I.e

Job_Ref / Name / Sales / Total

123 / VAT / 10.0

123 / DUTY / 10.0

123 / GHC / 10.0 / 30.0

SELECT DISTINCT ;

```
Job.cJobRef AS JobRef,;
Job.cName AS Customer_Name, ;
Job.cJobType AS JobType, ;
Job.cJobMode AS JobMode, ;
Job.cOrigin AS Org,;
Job.cDestination AS Dest,;
Job.cOwner AS Owner,;
jobcharge.cInvoiceDescr as [Invoice_Desc], ;
jobcharge.nAccrInv as [Accrued_Costs], ;
jobcharge.nCostInv as [Actual_Costs], ;
jobcharge.nSaleInv as [Sales], ;
( SELECT SUM(jobcharge.nAccrInv) AS SalesTotals FROM jobcharge WHERE NJOBID =3524); FROM job;INNER JOIN jobcharge ON job.nJob_Id = jobcharge.nJobId; WHERE job.cJobRef= "RSJC00001" AND job.cOwner = 'DBQ'
```

Thanks Ross

Answer (score 0):

(Too much to put into a comment field)... will answer later.

What is the purpose of your nJobID = 3524, are you only interested in one job?  If so, your query will give you the total only for job 3525 regardless of all the jobs returned from the JOB's WHERE clause.

I'll work on the query, but you do not want DISTINCT.

Additionally, you have just the jobCharge.nArrcInv, .nCostInv, .nSaleInv, but later you use SUM( jobcharge.nAccrInv )...  Is your INTENT to get a sum of accrued costs, sum of actual costs, sum of sales per job description??? inclusive of other job header content?

It looks like you want both individual sub-group totals per type of job activity PLUS the grand total of all sales across the entire job...  maybe what you want is this...

```
SELECT 
      Job.cJobRef AS JobRef,;
      Job.cName AS Customer_Name, ;
      Job.cJobType AS JobType, ;
      Job.cJobMode AS JobMode, ;
      Job.cOrigin AS Org,;
      Job.cDestination AS Dest,;
      Job.cOwner AS Owner,;
      JCSubTotals.Invoice_Desc,;
      JCSubTotals.Accrued_PerDesc,;
      JCSubTotals.Actual_PerDesc,;
      JCSubTotals.Sales_PerDesc,;
      JCFinalTotals.Total_Accrued,;
      JCFinalTotals.Total_Actual,;
      JCFinalTotals.Total_Sales;
   from ;
      ( select jc.nJobID,;
               jc.cInvoiceDescr as Invoice_Desc, ;
               sum( jc.nAccrInv ) as Accrued_PerDesc, ;
               sum( jc.nCostInv ) as Actual_PerDesc, ;
               sum( jc.nSaleInv ) as Sales_PerDesc ;
            from ;
               JobCharge jc;
            where ;
               jc.nJobID = 3524 ;
            group by ;
               jc.nJobID,;
               jc.cInvoiceDescr ) JCSubtotals ;
      JOIN ;
         ( select jc.nJobID,;
                  sum( jc.nAccrInv ) as Total_Accrued, ;
                  sum( jc.nCostInv ) as Total_Actual, ;
                  sum( jc.nSaleInv ) as Total_Sales ;
               from ;
                  JobCharge jc;
               where ;
                  jc.nJobID = 3524 ;
               group by ;
                  jc.nJobID ) JCFinalTotals ;
            ON JCSubtotals.nJobID = JCFinalTotals.nJobID ;
      JOIN Job ;
         on JCSubtotals.nJobID = Job.nID;
```

I've actually given you a few more columns to show on an every row, its Totals per job description, AND, the TOTALS compared to the entire job (for accrued, actual and sales).  You can always ignore the columns you don't care about, but this gives you a how to of what I think you want.

In addition, the last join to the "JOB" table I am assuming (since not provided), its primary key column is just "nID" instead of "nJob_ID" (as foreign key to the jobCharge table).

If you wanted these results spanning an entire set of jobs, I would actually just remove the  respective "WHERE" clauses from the JobCharge queries.

Comment: @Ross, revised answer to include query from perceived wanted results